# How to fix "ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed: null" while trying to make post call in KARATE DSL?

Tags: karate

Below is my feature file content. While executing the runner class for this feature file I am facing this error "16:09:06.508 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed: null".

```
Feature: To test POST leads API

Scenario: Test with valid flow
Given url leads
And request { "lastName": "Anderson", "email": "sam.anderson@matrix.com",    "phoneNumber": 39123345,    "privacyVersion": "1.1",    "marketing": true }
When method post
Then status 200
And match response == {"referenceId": '#notnull'}
And match response == {"referenceId": '#string'}
```

Get request is working fine.

Comment: What is `Given url leads`? Are you sure this is a valid url?

Comment: My bad , I did not append the base URL to leads, Thanks @peter . It worked

Comment: the un-helpful error message will be fixed in the next version 0.9.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the `url` is mal-formed and does not start with `http`.

Note that the un-helpful error message will be [fixed](https://github.com/intuit/karate/commit/376ebf53a0f57cf387c54d2cd857d048689f060b) in the next version (0.9.4)

Answer (score 0):

For us the problem was apache httpclient 4.5.13 , turns out that karate 0.9.2 didn't work well with it

taking a lower version 4.5.5 for example - solved the problem until we will upgrade.